# Assertion failure in UITableViewController occurs only with push and not with modal transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

**Disclaimer:** I assure you, this question is **not a duplicate** to the other posts out there. I understand when the error is produced but can confirm to you that this error should not be produced at all considering the situation I describe below.

I have an issue at the moment with one of my `UITableViewControllers`. 
When I connect the prototype cell in the `parent TBVC` to the `child table view controller` via a `modal transition` then all the cells load correctly with the information displayed properly too; this proves that there are no prototype identifier linking problems. 
However, using a `modal transition` causes my navigation bar to disappear so I opt for the standard `push` transition instead and this is where the problem occurs. The program produces the `Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.21/UITableView.m:7344` error.

This is highly frustrating as this error normally occurs when a cell is not being generated in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. But through debugging I can see that the cells are most certainly created:

```
2015-01-17 17:44:12.284 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 0
2015-01-17 17:44:12.294 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Monday hoursLabel.text: 9:00am - 5:30pm
2015-01-17 17:44:12.294 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.299 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 1
2015-01-17 17:44:12.307 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Tuesday hoursLabel.text: 9:00am - 5:30pm
2015-01-17 17:44:12.308 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.311 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 2
2015-01-17 17:44:12.320 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Wednesday hoursLabel.text: 9:00am - 5:30pm
2015-01-17 17:44:12.320 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.324 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 3
2015-01-17 17:44:12.332 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Thursday hoursLabel.text: 9:00am - 5:30pm
2015-01-17 17:44:12.332 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.336 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 4
2015-01-17 17:44:12.343 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Friday hoursLabel.text: 9:00am - 5:30pm
2015-01-17 17:44:12.344 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.346 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 5
2015-01-17 17:44:12.350 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Saturday hoursLabel.text: Closed
2015-01-17 17:44:12.351 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.353 PK[448:29784] cellForRowAtIndexPath: 6
2015-01-17 17:44:12.357 PK[448:29784] self.daysLabel.text: Sunday hoursLabel.text: Closed
2015-01-17 17:44:12.357 PK[448:29784] is cell nill: not nil
2015-01-17 17:44:12.361 PK[448:29784] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3318.16.21/UITableView.m:7344
2015-01-17 17:44:12.366 PK[448:29784] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184c2259c 0x1953800e4 0x184c2245c 0x185aa9554 0x18951391c 0x1896caf10 0x1896bfaa4 0x1894b4ce8 0x1893d1648 0x188d29994 0x188d24564 0x188d24408 0x188d23c08 0x188d2398c 0x188d1d3bc 0x184bdaa50 0x184bd79dc 0x184bd7dbc 0x184b050a4 0x18dca75a4 0x18943a3c0 0x1000fe31c 0x1959eea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have also tried linking the two view controllers manually instead by using the `didSelect` method and calling the `performSegue` method instead but this also produces the same result when trying to push onto the child table view controller.

Could someone please give me an insight as to what I can do to fix this problem.

**Update 1**
As requested by @paulw11 this is what the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method looks like. Again this loads all the cells correctly when transitioning into the table view controller `modally`, but then the assertion error occurs when I change the transition to a `push` style.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath: %lu", indexPath.row);
    OXHoursTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellIdentifierDaysSelection];

    [cell updateCellWithObject:self.businessHours[indexPath.row]];
    //In this method I simply grab the values of the object's attributes and assign them to the cell's two label's text property

    NSLog(@"is cell nill: %@", cell == nil ? @"nil" : @"not nil");
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: When you debug it, what is the value returned in your child VC for numberOfRowsInSection? It appears your child VC is expecting more than 7 rows, but your data source has only 7.

Comment: The number returned in the numberOfRowsInSection is 7. It's a constant. Remember, this viewcontroller works perfectly fine when modal transitioning into the child, but as soon as you push into it then the error happens. Ergh

Comment: Please show your code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: `UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` -- That seems pretty explicit to me.  Stupid question:  Are you sure that the error is occurring in that specific TableView with that specific dataSource, or did you just switch to a different one?  Also, did you register `kTableViewCellIdentifierDaysSelection`?

Comment: Hey @HotLicks, Yes I am certain. There are no other tableviews, its only the one in that single child controller. Also, the `kTableViewCellIdentifierDaysSelection` is indeed registered hence why its working when I simply transition modally but fails when transitioning with a push. Can we perhaps jump on a short screen sharing session to figure out whats going on?

Comment: Add `NSLog(@"The cell class is a %@, which %s a subclass of UITableViewCell", NSStringFromClass([cell class]), [cell isKindOfClass [UITableViewCell class]] ? "is" : "is not");` after your nil test log.

Comment: @HotLicks I can see what you're doing, clever. I will do that now and post the results shortly.

Comment: This is what is printed `The cell class is a OXHoursTableViewCell, which is a subclass of UITableViewCell` @HotLicks

Comment: All of a sudden the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method is not even being called at all. This would suggest that the `numberOfRowsForSection` returns 0 when it in fact returns 7 and is being called after nslogging everywhere. Can we screenshare if thats possible @HotLicks

Comment: I wonder if your dataSource class is being deleted due to a lack of strong references?

Comment: I think you might need to post this project somewhere if you want it solved.  I can't see any reason that you would get different results with a push vs. a modal presentation.

Comment: @rdelmar ok, no problem. I will try and upload the project as soon as I can, hopefully by the end of the week.